# Sum of two orthogonal set in hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let H be a Hilbert space. Let E and F both are closed subsets in H. Assume that both are orthogonal to each other. How to show that linear sum E+F is also closed.

Comment: I was trying sequential criterion  Let $x_{n} + y_{n} $ is a sequence in the sum which converge  to a in H now i tring to prove sequences converge individually  by using orthogonality...

Comment: what do we know about $d(x_n+y_n,x+y)$?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $d(e+f,e'+f')=\sqrt{\langle(e-e')+(f-f'),(e-e')+(f-f')\rangle}=\sqrt{d(e,e')^2+d(f,f')^2}$.

So now suppose that we have a cauchy sequence $(e_n,f_n)$ of this type. We can prove from the above formula that $(e_n)$ and $(f_n)$ are also cauchy sequences. And thus $(e_n)$ converges to a certain $e$ and $(f_n)$ to a certain $f$.

Finally use the formula once more to show $(e_n,f_n)$ converges to $(e,f)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any sequence $(x_n +y_n)$ in $E+F$ with $x_n \in E$ and $y_n \in F$ for all $n$. Suppose it converges to some $z \in H$. Since $E$ and $F$ are closed subspaces we can define $P_E$ and $P_F$ as the orthogonal projection onto the respective spaces. Because $E$ and $F$ are orthogonal we have $(P_E + P_F)(x_n+y_n) = (x_n+y_n)$ for all $n$. Taking the limit, we then find by the continuity of $P_E$ and $P_F$ that $z = P_E z+ P_F z \in E+F$. So we conclude $E+F$ is closed.